# Rewriting URLs with htaccess for multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/pages/article.html?id=1&title=Title-Goes-Here
```

into

```
https://mywebsite.com/pages/article/1/Title-Goes-Here
```

Using this Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ article.html?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

However, when I try this code in https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ it gives me

> This rule was not met.

Also tried it on my website htaccess file with no result. I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

from stackoverflow

Using this in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect in browser rules here....
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.html\?id=([^&]*)&title=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to html file rules here....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  $1/$2.html?id=$3&title=$4 [QSA,NC,L]
```

and this in article.html right after head opening tag

```
<base href="/" />
```

All is working as intended. Someone helped me with that code :)